# How can I update the state of my menu only on the first time my component renders?

Tags: reactjs, components, render, lifecycle

I have an application that is called with arguments.  Right now, my menu always loads to the default MainMenu.  I would like to be able to pass in a state to Menu.js and start with a different menu opened, instead of the default MainMenu.

I thought componentWillMount() would enable me to set my state to a menu state of my choice, but for whatever reason it's not updating the rendered content.  When I call it, this.state.Selected becomes the correct menu name that I want to render...but it doesn't actually render - It ends up rendering the default menu.

So I have to call something else after componentWillMount() in order to get it to actually render?

Landing.js -  calls Menu.js.  I would like to render the menu 'FileOptions' first.  However, it is currently rendering MainMenu.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import sass from '../scss/application.scss'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Header from './Header'
import Menu from './Menu'
import HelpFile from './HelpFile'



class Landing extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = { 
             helpFileName: 'Mainmenu',
             menuName: 'FileOptions',
         }
       }

    handleHelpChange(helpFileName) {
        this.setState( {helpFileName} );
    }

    handleMenuClick(menuName) {
        this.setState( {menuName} );
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        let hlpString = require('electron').remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').hlpOne;
        if (hlpString != null && hlpString != '.')
        {
            this.setState({
                helpFileName: hlpString
            });ss
        }
    }

    render() {  

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Header />
                </div>
                <br /><br />
                <div className="mainMenuDiv">
                    <Menu handleHelpChange={this.handleHelpChange.bind(this)} menuName={this.state.menuName}/>
                </div>
                <div className="mainContainerDiv">
                    <HelpFile name={this.state.helpFileName}/>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}


export default Landing;
```

Menu.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import sass from '../scss/application.scss'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'



class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = { 
             Selected: props.menuName,      // reads FileOptions, but still renders MainMenu
             name: ''
         }
       }

    handleChange(name) {
        this.setState({
            name: name
        });
    }

    handleClick(e, num) {
        this.setState({
            name: num
          }, () => {
            let helpFileName = num;
            helpFileName = helpFileName.toLowerCase().trim();
            //Cap the first letter in the name and add the rest of the name 
            helpFileName = helpFileName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + helpFileName.substr(1);
            this.props.handleHelpChange(helpFileName);
          });
      }

     handleMenuClick(e, num, opt) {
        this.setState({
            name: num,
            Selected: opt
          }, () => {
            let helpFileName = num;
            helpFileName = helpFileName.toLowerCase().trim();
            //Cap the first letter in the name and add the rest of the name 
            helpFileName = helpFileName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + helpFileName.substr(1);
            this.props.handleHelpChange(helpFileName);
          });
      }

    render() {
        const MainMenu = () => (
            <div>
                <button 
                    label="File Options"
                    //onClick={() => this.setState({ Selected: FileOptions })} 
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleMenuClick(e, 'Fileopt', FileOptions)}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >FILE OPTIONS</button>
                <button 
                    label="Setup Options"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleMenuClick(e, 'Setupopt', SetUpOptions)}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >SETUP OPTIONS</button>
                <button 
                    label="Lumber Options"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleMenuClick(e, 'Lumberopt', MoreOptions)}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >MORE OPTIONS</button>
                <button 
                    label="Main Menu"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'Mainmenu')} 
                    className="aPrevButton"
                >MAIN MENU</button>
            </div>
        );

        const FileOptions = () => (
            <div>
                <button 
                    label="Option One"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'Option One')}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >Option One</button>
               <button 
                    label="Option Two"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'Option Two')}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >Option Two</button>
                <button 
                    label="Option Three"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'Option Three')}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >Option Three</button>
                <button 
                    label="Option Four"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'Option Four')}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >Option Four</button>
                <button 
                    label="Previous Menu"
                    onClick={() => this.setState({ Selected: MainMenu })} 
                    className="aPrevButton"
                >PREVIOUS MENU</button>
            </div>
        );

        const SetUpOptions = () => (
            <div>
                <button 
                    label="Option One"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'Option One')}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >Option One</button>
               <button 
                    label="Option Two"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'Option Two')}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >Option Two</button>
                <button 
                    label="Option Three"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'Option Three')}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >Option Three</button>
                <button 
                    label="Previous Menu"
                    onClick={() => this.setState({ Selected: MainMenu })} 
                    className="aPrevButton"
                >PREVIOUS MENU</button>
            </div>
        );

        const MoreOptions = () => (
            <div>
                <button 
                    label="Option One"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'Option One')}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >Option One</button>
               <button 
                    label="Option Two"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'Option Two')}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >Option Two</button>
                <button 
                    label="Option Three"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'Option Three')}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >Option Three</button>
                <button 
                    label="Option Four"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, 'Option Four')}
                    className="aMenuButton"
                >Option Four</button>
                <button 
                    label="Previous Menu"
                    onClick={() => this.setState({ Selected: MainMenu })} 
                    className="aPrevButton"
                >PREVIOUS MENU</button>
            </div>
        );

        const { Selected } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>   
                <div className="menuButtons">
                    {Selected === 'MainMenu' ? <MainMenu /> : <Selected /> }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Menu.propTypes = {  
    handleHelpChange: PropTypes.func,
    name: PropTypes.string,
    menuName: PropTypes.string
}


export default Menu;
```

Comment: I think there is a bug in your render function in Menu. You can't just change a string to React component. if Selected = "FileOptions", you can't do <Selected /> and expect it will be <FileOptions />.   I am not sure why it will render MainMenu, you might want to check what is returned from `require('electron').remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').hlpOne`

Comment: the sharedObject renders page content and doesn't mess the menu up.  Right now <Selected /> renders MainMenu or FileOptions because of const { Selected } = this.state.  When a menu item is clicked the state is updated and a function is called causing the component to re-render.  The entire menu system works fine, it just always has to start from MainMenu.  Was hoping to find a way to start from a different menu point, such as FileOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [react docs for `componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount),

> `componentWillMount()` is invoked immediately before mounting occurs.
>   It is called before `render()`, therefore setting state synchronously
>   in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any
>   side-effects or subscriptions in this method. This is the only
>   lifecycle hook called on server rendering. Generally, we recommend
>   using the `constructor()` instead.

**Update 1**

Set your selected menu name in constructor and remove setState from componentWillMount.

**Update 2**

@Yiou noticed that `<Selected />` is not a component.

```
class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { 
        Selected: props.menuName || '',
        name: ''
      }
    }

  // ....

  render() {

    // after you created all your menu constant implement a switch to select
    // which menu is going to render
    const { Selected } = this.state;
    let SelectedMenu;
    switch(Selected) {
      case 'MainMenu':
        SelectedMenu = MainMenu;
        break;
      case 'FileOptions':
        SelectedMenu = FileOptions;
        break;
      default:
        SelectedMenu = MainMenu;
        break;
    }

    return (
        <div>   
            <div className="menuButtons">
                {SelectedMenu()}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }    
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, I have the constructor set.  If I set Selected: this.props.menuName inside of the constructor - I get the same results.

Comment: @user3622460 updated answer with a piece of code that might help you

Comment: Ah, that's what I had before introducing componentWillMount.  Doesn't work.  If I set menuName to 'FileOptions', the menu will fail to load.  For whatever reason, if I don't pass in MainMenu it will fail to load any menu at all.

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't make sense. Even if you didn't sen any props to your Menu component it should render `<Selected />`. There are bunch of extra `s` letters in your code. I thought they are typo but now I'm thinking they might be the cause of problem. Please check your code and update your question with any changes you made in your code.

Comment: Those are typo's -fixing them now

Comment: Ok. I understood the problem. @Yiou was correct on his comment. I'm updating my answer in a sec.

Comment: I like the idea of the switch statement, but it doesn't work.  I added the switch statement and {SelectedMenu} to the return div and nothing returns.  However, it has zero errors in console.  I'm wondering if a function has to be invoked in order to render out a component

Comment: change `SelectedMenu` to `SelectedMenu()`

Comment: You got it.  Thank you.  I can't walk into the other sub menu options, but I have a feeling if I just add them to the switch statement they will also work.

Comment: So you can start at a certain menu with this, but you can't progress to sub menu's with the switch statement.  Is their a component I should call within handleMenuClick to update SelectedMenu to cause it to re-render?  The correct helpfile is being rendered, but the menu isn't progressing to the FileOptions sub menu

Comment: Correct menu rendering is related to correct menu name passing to Menu component and getting selected correctly through the switch. Mine was just an example of showing you a way.You should create your own logic according to the knowledge you get. Might sound arrogant and not helpful but I can't just code all the logic for you. I'm just trying to show you a way.

Comment: Well if you look my logic was working.  I could navigate all menu's and move around.  The only thing I wanted to add was to the ability to start on a sub menu.  I guess this method requires remaking the menu system, which seems like it will be a harder than finding a different solution to start on a sub menu